# Outlook app Inbox font too small out of nowhere

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I don't understand why this happened, but suddenly, my fonts were really small in my Inbox list. I don't think I changed anything, but I suspect it was a key-stroke assignment that I intended for another software.

I fixed this issue using another suggestion from a similar error posted on this site. In the View Tab, I selected Compact, then selected "reset view," and it worked. My font is back to the proper size, and the layout is good.

So I am still not sure what caused it, but I am glad that the fix worked.

Answer (score 1):

The Fix that worked for me:

1. View Tab > Change View > Compact View
2. View Tab > Current view > Reset View

Comment: That is just settings - likely a bad keystroke. Nothing wrong with Outlook